# Is there a way to customize the folder name src-tauri/ to something else?

Tags: tauri

I am looking to building UI and tauri code as two different repositories. As part of this exploration, I was wondering if src-tauri folder can be renamed to something else? If yes, then where do we configure the new folder folder name?

Folder structure:

```
│── package.json
│── public
│   ╰── index.html
│── src
│   │── App.css
│   │── App.jsx
│   │── index.css
│   ╰── index.js
╰── tauriapp1
    │── Cargo.toml
    │── build.rs
    │── icons
    │── src
    ╰── tauri.conf.json
```

When I run "yarn tauri dev" from root folder, following error message is thrown.

thread 'main' panicked at 'Couldn't recognize the current folder as a Tauri project. It must contain a `tauri.conf.json`, `tauri.conf.json5` or `Tauri.toml` file in any subfolder.', C:\Users\user.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tauri-cli-1.1.1\src\helpers\app_paths.rs:79:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

---

**Apparently, .gitignore is the culprit! any folder that is part of .gitignore is not scanned.**

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if src-tauri folder can be renamed to something else?

Yes, Tauri does not care about the folder name, it actively searches for the config file starting from the current working dir. So as long as you make sure that the config file is reachable by traversing **down** the file tree from the location you run tauri commands in, it should keep working.

Comment: Yes. That is what I thought it would do. however, it doesn't seem to do so. I have added the folder structure.

Comment: Reference here: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/2752#issuecomment-1115443476